# Horizontal scale does not accurately correspond to bar charts

Tags: pgfplots

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn, openright]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Define bar chart colors
%
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (20em,20em) rectangle (5em,5em);
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 20cm,
        height = 8cm,
        % major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=0pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Bleu},
        % xtick = {fr2zh},
        % xticklabels = {fr2zh, de2zh, it2zh, ja2zh, ko2zh, vi2zh, null1, zh2de, zh2it, zh2ja, zh2ko, zh2vi, zh2fr},
        symbolic x coords={fr2zh, de2zh, it2zh, ja2zh, ko2zh, vi2zh, zh2de, zh2it, zh2ja, zh2ko, zh2vi, zh2fr, fr2de, fr2it, fr2ja, fr2ko, fr2vi, de2fr, de2it, de2ja, de2ko, de2vi, it2fr, it2de, it2ja, it2ko, it2vi, ja2fr, ja2de, ja2it, ja2ko, ja2vi, ko2fr, ko2de, ko2it, ko2ja, ko2vi, vi2fr, vi2de, vi2it, vi2ja, vi2ko},
        xtick = {fr2zh, de2zh, it2zh, ja2zh, ko2zh, vi2zh,zh2de, zh2it, zh2ja, zh2ko, zh2vi, zh2fr, fr2de, fr2it, fr2ja, fr2ko, fr2vi, de2fr, de2it, de2ja, de2ko, de2vi, it2fr, it2de, it2ja, it2ko, it2vi, ja2fr, ja2de, ja2it, ja2ko, ja2vi, ko2fr, ko2de, ko2it, ko2ja, ko2vi, vi2fr, vi2de, vi2it, vi2ja, vi2ko},
        % xtick = data,
        bar width=0.6em,%<- changed
        xticklabel style={
            inner sep=0pt,
            anchor=north east,
            rotate=60,
            font = \tiny,
        },
        scaled y ticks = false,
        % enlarge x limits=0.2,
        ymin=0,
        % legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                legend columns=-1,
                column sep=1ex,
        }
    ]
        \addplot[style={blue!20,fill=blue!20,mark=none}]
            coordinates {(fr2zh, 32.3) (de2zh,17.5) (it2zh,29.5) (ja2zh,26.4) (ko2zh,26.8) (vi2zh,30.4)};

        \addplot[style={red!20,fill=red!20,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(zh2de,29.7) (zh2it,25.8) (zh2ja,23.7) (zh2ko,21.6) (zh2vi,32.3) (zh2fr,35.5) };

        \addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(fr2de,32.4)
             (fr2it,28.3) (fr2ja,24.6) (fr2ko,21.5) (fr2vi,34.5) (de2fr,37.6) (de2it,27.7) (de2ja,24) (de2ko,21.6) (de2vi,33.8) (it2fr,35.6) (it2de,29.3) (it2ja,22.8) (it2ko,20.2) (it2vi,31.6) (ja2fr,29.7) (ja2de,24.3) (ja2it,22.2) (ja2ko,20.7) (ja2vi,27.6) (ko2fr,30) (ko2de,25.6) (ko2it,21.7) (ko2ja,22.7) (ko2vi,28.3) (vi2fr,34.2) (vi2de,28.5) (vi2it,24.5) (vi2ja,22.8) (vi2ko,21)};

        % \addplot[style={ppurple,fill=ppurple,mark=none}]
        %      coordinates {(EgyptHD,0.74) (Hover,1.07) (Navi,1.23)};

        \legend{source2zh,zh2target,source2target}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn, openright]{report}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}  % <---
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Define bar chart colors
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = \linewidth,%20cm,
        height = 8cm,
%
        ybar=-0.6em,                    % <---
        bar width=0.6em, 
%       
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Bleu},
        symbolic x coords={fr2zh, de2zh, it2zh, ja2zh, ko2zh, vi2zh, zh2de, zh2it, zh2ja, zh2ko, zh2vi, zh2fr, fr2de, fr2it, fr2ja, fr2ko, fr2vi, de2fr, de2it, de2ja, de2ko, de2vi, it2fr, it2de, it2ja, it2ko, it2vi, ja2fr, ja2de, ja2it, ja2ko, ja2vi, ko2fr, ko2de, ko2it, ko2ja, ko2vi, vi2fr, vi2de, vi2it, vi2ja, vi2ko},
        xtick = {fr2zh, de2zh, it2zh, ja2zh, ko2zh, vi2zh,zh2de, zh2it, zh2ja, zh2ko, zh2vi, zh2fr, fr2de, fr2it, fr2ja, fr2ko, fr2vi, de2fr, de2it, de2ja, de2ko, de2vi, it2fr, it2de, it2ja, it2ko, it2vi, ja2fr, ja2de, ja2it, ja2ko, ja2vi, ko2fr, ko2de, ko2it, ko2ja, ko2vi, vi2fr, vi2de, vi2it, vi2ja, vi2ko},
        % xtick = data,
        xticklabel style={
            inner sep=0pt,
            anchor=north east,
            rotate=60,
            font = \tiny,
        },
%
        enlarge x limits={abs=1em},
        ymin=0,
        % legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                legend columns=-1,
                column sep=1ex,
        }
    ]
        \addplot[style={blue!20,fill=blue!20,mark=none}]
            coordinates {(fr2zh, 32.3) (de2zh,17.5) (it2zh,29.5) (ja2zh,26.4) (ko2zh,26.8) (vi2zh,30.4)};

        \addplot[style={red!20,fill=red!20,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(zh2de,29.7) (zh2it,25.8) (zh2ja,23.7) (zh2ko,21.6) (zh2vi,32.3) (zh2fr,35.5) };

        \addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(fr2de,32.4)
             (fr2it,28.3) (fr2ja,24.6) (fr2ko,21.5) (fr2vi,34.5) (de2fr,37.6) (de2it,27.7) (de2ja,24) (de2ko,21.6) (de2vi,33.8) (it2fr,35.6) (it2de,29.3) (it2ja,22.8) (it2ko,20.2) (it2vi,31.6) (ja2fr,29.7) (ja2de,24.3) (ja2it,22.2) (ja2ko,20.7) (ja2vi,27.6) (ko2fr,30) (ko2de,25.6) (ko2it,21.7) (ko2ja,22.7) (ko2vi,28.3) (vi2fr,34.2) (vi2de,28.5) (vi2it,24.5) (vi2ja,22.8) (vi2ko,21)};

        \legend{source2zh,zh2target,source2target}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Main changes in my MWE in comparison to yours are in code marked by `<---`.

Comment: I added some code to make the bar chart representable in piles, but the split line does not appear between the first and second piles.